# GTK3 ComboboxText on touchscreen

Tags: perl, combobox, gtk3, touchscreen

I have a problem with above mentioned widget on touchscreen (Elo). List of options is visible only while widget is pressed. This is different behavior to that one with mouse as pointer. After mouse left click list of options appears and waits for user choice.

I`m using Perl 5.22,  and GTK3 (3.18.2) and Perl Gtk3 wrapper library (0.025).

Comment: Have you tried running a basic version of your program written in C (without any wrappers)? Does it exhibit the same behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is likely due to this bug (which has not yet been fixed) in GTK3:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=333470

It seems that if you move the mouse pointer at all after pressing on the combo box (which is likely to happen on a touchscreen) it will be interpreted as a selection, instead of keeping the options open for selection.